# HBASE Bulk-Load in multiple region for a single table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

I am trying to Load data in `HBase` using `BulkLoad`. I am also using `Scala` and `Spark` to write the code. But every time data is loading on only one single region. I need to load this into multiple region. I have used below code -

**Hbase Configuration**:

```
def getConf: Configuration = {
    val hbaseSitePath = "/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    conf.addResource(new Path(hbaseSitePath))
    conf.setInt("hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily", 100)
    conf   
}
```

I can load 80GB of Data in only one single region using above mentioned configuration.

But when I am trying load the same amount of data in multiple region with below mentioned configuration getting exception

> java.io.IOException: Trying to load more than 32 hfiles to one family
>   of one region

**Updated Configuration** -

```
def getConf: Configuration = {

  val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  conf.addResource(new Path(hbaseSitePath))
  conf.setInt("hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily", 32)

  conf.setLong("hbase.hregion.max.filesize", 107374182)
  conf.set("hbase.regionserver.region.split.policy","org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy")
  conf
}
```

For saving records I am using below code -

```
val kv = new KeyValue(Bytes.toBytes(key), columnFamily.getBytes(),
        columnName.getBytes(), columnValue.getBytes())

      (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(key)), kv)

rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(pathToHFile, classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[KeyValue],
      classOf[HFileOutputFormat2], conf) //Here rdd is the input

    val loadFiles = new LoadIncrementalHFiles(conf)
    loadFiles.doBulkLoad(new Path(pathToHFile), hTable)
```

Need Help on this.

Comment: Are your row keys sequential? When you write records with sequential keys to Hbase, HBase hits only one Region. This behaviour is specific to HBase and has nothing to do with using Spark. Check this article out:
https://sematext.com/blog/2012/04/09/hbasewd-avoid-regionserver-hotspotting-despite-writing-records-with-sequential-keys/

Comment: I am saving the key like 001_16062017105407, 002_16062017105455, 003_16062017105505 and ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting issue because 32 is default value per region. You should define `KeyPrefixRegionSplitPolicy` to split your files and you can increase increase `hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily` as below

```
conf.setInt("hbase.mapreduce.bulkload.max.hfiles.perRegion.perFamily", 1024)
```

Try also to increase file size as

```
  conf.setLong("hbase.hregion.max.filesize", 107374182)
```